# Can GenAI have the option to switch on a dark theme (like how StackOverflow does)?

Tags: feature-request

The bright white background gets a bit tough on the eyes after a while, and I'd love to spend more time reading through the multiple interesting questions and answers here. Would it be possible for this site to have a dark theme, or is it necessary to wait until it gets out of beta mode, to be able to add such features?

Comment: Upvoted, but dark mode has been requested on _many_ sites, and it largely hasn’t happened. There’s a _chance_ they might for all sites using the default theme (including this site), but also don’t be surprised if this gets declined.

Comment: I think the issue is that it clashes with site design.

Comment: But StackOverflow's dark theme works fine. May I know how it clashes with site design? It always helps to reduce the brightness of screen light reaching our eyes, especially at night. Helps the intraocular muscles avoid strain.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/) is how it ended up on Stack Overflow; the process is quite complicated.  Sites are professionally designed with a lot of details in mind, many elements to individually change on each site, colors to balance, and so on.  Dark mode is [a popular idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111399/dark-mode-for-stack-exchange-sites), but it doesn't seem likely any time soon as it's too complicated.  It could also end up de-prioritizing ongoing site design.  (I use the Dark Reader browser extension.  It's okay.)

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned by cocomac in a question comment, the dark theme was asked before in other Stack Exchange communities, and apparently, there isn't any that that got that feature yet, even Stack Overflow Meta

Please don't get me wrong; your general question is fine; it might require retagging as it requires more details. Let's see what the Staff tells us about the specifics. In the meantime, I will add some stuff here that might help.

##### Meta Stack Exchange

- [dark-mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-mode).
  This link points to the list of questions tagged `dark-mode`. At this time, there are 34 questions.
- [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/1359324).
  This `feature-request` was created in 2011. It hasn't a status tag yet, but several answers provide workarounds like using a userscript.
- [Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359739/1359324).
  This discussion was created in 2021.
- [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/1359324)
  This Staff post was created in 2018. It's not directly related to the theme-switching feature but is about site theme design customization. I wonder if the GenAI might be dark.

##### Meta Stack Overflow

- [When does Dark Mode come to Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404540/21769175)
  This `feature-request` was created in 2021. It hasn't a status tag yet

Answer (score 3):

There are user-generated dark mode userscripts around.

For example  [Here on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/8053/32479)

And some of the site metas have similar that are optimised for their themes.

You could always experiment until an official theme comes along.

Comment: Hey, this is nice! However, I am a bit wary of using TamperMonkey.

Comment: @Nav why?~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Due to ignorance, mostly. I'd have to fully verify the script that somebody wrote. I remember reading online, about somebody getting infected with malware because they used some script with TamperMonkey. I just realized that I could get ChatGPT to check the script...

Answer (score 2):

> Can GenAI have the option to switch on a dark theme (like how StackOverflow does)?

One can use one's browser dark mode. E.g., Chrome's built-in dark mode works well with the SE beta template that GenAI uses.

Comment: I remember Chrome having a dark mode extension. So does Firefox. Problem is, they dont always darken sites correctly.

Comment: @Nav the extension is called Dark Reader. I barely use it any more, as it adds a bit of lag and Chrome's built-in dark mode works well with most sites.